# Can't pass Terraform Output variables to another azure pipeline Job

Tags: variables, terraform, output, azure-pipelines-yaml

I need to pass some terraform outputs to a task (that trigger an azurefunction) in another job:

- TerraformTaskV3@3 is an agent pool task.
- AzureFunction@1 is a server pool task.

So both are on separate jobs.

I based my pipeline on following resources:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable

https://www.natmarchand.fr/using-terraform-output-values-in-azure-devops-pipeline/

```
stages:
  - stage: Deploy
    jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy
      environment: '$(devopsenvironment)'
      pool: 
        vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:      
            - download: $(pipeline)
            ....        
            - task: TerraformTaskV3@3
              name: terraformOutputTask
              displayName: 'Terraform : azurerm output'
              inputs:            
                command: output                
                environmentServiceNameAzureRM: $(serviceConnection)
                        - powershell: |
                $terraformOutput = Get-Content "$(terraformOutputTask.jsonOutputVariablesPath)" | ConvertFrom-Json
                $terraformOutput | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | % { $o = $terraformOutput.($_.Name); Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=$($_.Name);isoutput=true;issecret=$($o.sensitive)]$($o.value)" }
              name: terraformOutput
              displayName: Read terraform outputs 
            - script: |             
                echo t:storage_primary_connection_string - $(terraformOutput.storage_primary_connection_string)
                echo t:maintenance_function_base_url - $(terraformOutput.maintenance_function_base_url)
                echo t:maintenance_function_key - $(terraformOutput.maintenance_function_key)
              condition: eq(${{ parameters.outputvariables }}, true) 
              displayName: Display terraform ouput
            .....
    - job: Post_Deploy
      displayName: Post deployment tasks
      dependsOn: Deploy
      variables: 
        maintenance_function_base_url: $[ dependencies.Deploy.outputs['terraformOutput.maintenance_function_base_url'] ]
        maintenance_function_key: $[ dependencies.Deploy.outputs['terraformOutput.maintenance_function_key'] ]
      pool: server                  
      steps:                 
        ...
        # Import localization
        - task: AzureFunction@1
          displayName: 'Execute Azure Import Localization Function'
          condition: not(eq('$(maintenance_function_key)', ''))
          retryCountOnTaskFailure: 1
          inputs:
            function: 'https://$(maintenance_function_base_url)/api/ImportLocalization'
            key: '$(maintenance_function_key)'
            method: 'POST'
            body: ''                       
            waitForCompletion: 'true'
```

- Terraform task works as expected.
- Script that set variables seems to work as the next task displays correct values.
- AzureFunctionTask failed as $(maintenance_function_base_url) and $(maintenance_function_key) seem empty

Pipeline fails with:

URL https:///api/ImportLocalization?code=& for HttpRequest is not correct.
Deploy • Post deployment tasks • Execute Azure Import Localization Function

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrtB5.png)

Comment: Jobs run in independent machines. Setting an environment variable won't work because the machine running job a is not going to be the same machine in job b, plus the machines (should) be taken down to a base state for every job, essentially deleting all information stored on that machine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Azure Devops - passing variables between job templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59038584/azure-devops-passing-variables-between-job-templates)

Comment: refer to official Microsoft documentation to set variables that will be used by further stages/jobs, Explicit dependency is needed to fulfill this condition.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#set-an-output-variable-for-use-in-future-jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Ishuar direction I finaly pinpoint the source of the issue.

The mistake is that my server task refer an output defined in a Deployment job (and not a regular job).

So the dependency notation is slightly different than the one specified by microsoft documentation '**Set a multi-job output variable**'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable

For my case instead of using

```
maintenance_function_base_url: $[ dependencies.Deploy.outputs['terraformOutput.maintenance_function_base_url'] ]
```

I must use:

```
maintenance_function_base_url: $[ dependencies.Deploy.outputs['Deploy.terraformOutput.maintenance_function_base_url']
```

As stated in '**Deployment jobs - Support for output variables**'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops#support-for-output-variables

Note the notation is dependant of Deploy lifecycle (in my case runOnce)
If you use another you must check the documention.